# shard MySQL/Aurora DB by table name with maxscale

Tags: maxscale

I am wanting to split up our DB schema so that one of our session tables resides on its own DB and the remainder of the tables remain on the original server.

So, I want to configure the DB proxy to route all queries to the session table to "server_b" but keep all other requests to the original server ("server_a").

Is there a way to have maxscale redirect to a server based off of the table name, and not the schema?

The closest thing I have found is the [SchemaRouter](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-maxscale-24-schemarouter/), but this seems to be more of an "aggregator" than doing what I want.